# Random non repeating array JS (solving without .includes())

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need array with random non repeating values. I find solving with includes() but i want make without it.

CODE

```
function rand(min, max){
    return Math.round( Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function getRandArray(n, min, max) {
    //n - array length

    var randArr = [];
    randArr[0] = rand(min, max);

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    var randNum = rand(min, max);
        for (var j = 0; j < randArr.length; j++){
            if (randNum != randArr[j])
                randArr[i] = randNum;
            else 
                randNum = rand(min, max);
        }
    }
    return randArr;
}
```

Comment: Look into the [ES6 Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the power of the [ES6 Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to do this very easily. Since you are looking for an array output, you can simply use `Array.from` and pass in the set to return from the function. Here's what it would look like:

```js
function rand(min, max){
    return Math.round( Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
function getRandArr(n, min, max) {
  var set = new Set();
  // ensure that the number of unique numbers they want is possible
  var maxNumsInArr = Math.min(n, max-min+1);
  while(set.size < maxNumsInArr) {
    set.add(rand(min, max));
  }
  return Array.from(set);
}

console.log(getRandArr(10, 0, 10));
console.log(getRandArr(5, 100, 399));
console.log(getRandArr(5, 0, 2)); // only 3 possible unique values, so length will be 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If ES6 is not an option you can convert the random numbers into String keys for an object and take advantage of the fact that an object will not allow duplicate properties like this:

```
function rand(min, max){
    return Math.round( Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function getRandArr(n, min, max) {
    if (n > (max - min + 1)) {
        throw "Cannot create array of size " + n;
    }
    var res = {};
    while (Object.keys(res).length < n) {
        var r = rand(min, max);
        res[r] = true;
    }
    var array = Object.keys(res);
    return array;
}

console.log(getRandArr(100, 0, 10000));
```

You could always convert the array of Strings back to numbers with a single pass after you have the results.

Adding a property to an object will use a hash of the property name so you get O(1) time for checking if the number is unique.

Comment: I missed this originally, too, but if they use `getRandArr(5, 0, 2)` it will infinitely loop. I updated my post with a solution to this issue, but there are many other ways to handle it

Comment: Yep that is true; perhaps throw is the correct response in such a case.

Comment: @mhodges Have to be careful if they supply a min that is larger than max as well but that that seems outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Yes, agreed. We can't know for sure what the OP wants to do, but it is good to at least throw it out there for future viewers